# Server Platform for Audio Processing

Tags: java, c, audio-processing, jack, pulseaudio

I'm trying to build a server for processing audio from an incoming UDP connection. I need to be able to do things like change the frequency of the incoming stream (probably a .wav), the amplitude, time shift it, etc. then feed the output back out in real time. The language would be either C/C++/ObjC or Java, or a combination of both (if it is fast enough)

What I've seen so far is mention of Jack and PulseAudio on several forums. However, what I don't know is which of these suits my needs the best. I've heard from a friend who does audio processing that these two frameworks have a rather large codebase.  Which platform would be best suited for my needs, and which would you recommend?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What are you *really* trying to do?

Comment: I think I've laid out all the details above, what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what platform you are working on. Regarding your choice of Objective-C, I assume it is MacOS. In this case you may consider using AudioQueue. It is well documented by Apple and relatively easy to use (they've got an example of streaming audio over network using AudioQueue). If you are not doing very fancy stuff, java can handle it as well, btw.